# nginx choosing wrong virtual host

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-20.04

(disclaimer: yes, I know there's a ton of these questions, but I did search for about a half hour before posting this)

I'm trying to setup zabbix to monitor nginx using `ngx_http_stub_status_module` by following [this tutorial](https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/nginx#tab:official2).

this is on my dev server so the configuration files are simple... my main sites .conf file is...

**example.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/example.com/example;
    }


    location / {

                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.example.sock;
    }
}
```

and then I wanted a separate virtual host for the monitoring, if nothing else than just practice

**basic_status.conf**

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name localhost;

        access_log      /var/log/nginx/server_status.log main;

        location = /basic_status {
                stub_status;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
            }
}
```

for the `basic_status.conf` file, I've tried the following as well

```
listen 127.0.0.1;
server_name 127.0.0.1;
server_name localhost.test;  #with a corresponding  127.0.0.1 localhost.test in /etc/hosts
```

and to access the page I've tried...

```
curl localhost/basic_status
curl localhost
curl 127.0.0.1/basic_status
curl 17.0.0.1
curl localhost.test/basic_status
curl localhost.test
```

but all I get is.

```
[error] 2467#2467: *1 connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.example.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/run/gunicorn.example.sock:/", host: "localhost"
```

I'm not wanting to use default_server simply for the sake of practicing\learning how to do this properly.

I know the answer will probably be simple and obvious...  :-)  But I'm at a loss now.

**EDIT:**
file locations are

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.conf
/etc/nginx/sites-available/basic_status.conf
```

both with  with symlinks to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

with Ubuntu 20.04

**EDIT2:**

turns out I actually didn't have `.conf` at the end of basic_status, it wasn't until doing what Richard Smith in the comments suggested and doing `nginx -T` that I saw it wasn't even picking up that file.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration that Nginx is reading and ensure that the `server` block is present with a `server_name` that exactly matches the domain name used in the `curl` command.

Comment: What is the distribution you are using? What are the full paths to the confg files you use?

Comment: I'm an idiot. after doing what Richard Smith suggested, I see that basic_status wasn't being picked up, after taking a closer look, it actually DIDN't have '.conf', but was just... `basic_status`....    oh well, I won't delete this in the off chance these comments help someone, and so everyone will feel a little better about making dumb mistakes

Comment: You should just post an answer. You did solve the problem, after all.